# VBA Manually entered array - Zoidberg

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have VBA code that formats a range of cells, reads in a text file, converts the text in each cell to a color and in effect draws a picture of Zoidberg.

The problem I am having is the text file... I want to include the contents of the text file in the VBA as a manually entered array. That way I do not have to have the text file.  This is strictly a memory burner.

The text file is the same thing as an array (in theory), so I should be able to define the array and do all the same things I am doing with the text file... but I'm missing something how do set up the array...

```
 Sub Why_Not_Zoidberg()
         ' Insert Why Not Zoidberg?
         '

    'MAKE STUFF HAPPEN IN THE BACKGROUND
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    'DEFINE VARIABLES
    Dim Rng1 As Range



    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim nName As Name
    'SET RANGE
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:BN48")
    'CLEAR OUT ANY EXISTING JUNK
    With Rng1
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select


    'IMPORT TEXT FILE
    'With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    '    "TEXT;C:\Windows\Zoidberg.txt", Destination:=Rng1 _
    '    )
    '    .Name = "Sample"
    '    .FieldNames = True
    '    .RowNumbers = False
    '    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    '    .PreserveFormatting = True
    '    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    '    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    '    .SavePassword = False
    '    .SaveData = True
    '    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    '    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    '    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    '    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    '    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    '    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    '    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    '    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    '    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    '    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    '    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    '    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    '    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    '    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = False
    '    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    'End With
    ' ADD COLORS
    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
        If Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value = 3 Then
            Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 3, 74)
        End If
        If Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value = -4142 Then
            Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
        If Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value = 1 Then
            Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1, 1)
        End If
        If Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value = 14 Then
            Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 153)
        End If
      Next j
    Next i
    'CLEAR OUT TEXT FILE STUFF
    Rng1.Select
    With Rng1
        .ClearContents
    End With
    Rng1.Select
    'SET CELL SIZE
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 2
    Selection.RowHeight = 14.25
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'BREAK LINK TO EXTERNAL TEXT FILE
    For Each nName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
       If Left(nName.Name, 12) <> "" Then nName.Delete
    Next nName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Zoidberg.txt

```
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,14,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,1,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,14,14,14,14,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,14,14,14,14,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,14,14,14,14,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,1,-4142,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142,-4142
```

Comment: This Q&A may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938614/pre-defining-multi-dimensional-array-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

Every Excel worksheet is like a big 2d array. Depending on how you want to distribute the code, I'd store it in a worksheet. I copied and pasted your txt file into Excel - Paste Special - Text. Then I did Data - Text to Columns, delimited on Comma.  Then I changed the code to this

```
Sub Why_Not_Zoidberg()

    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim nName As Name

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:BN48")
    With Rng1
        .NumberFormat = ";;;" 'hide the values in the cells
        .ColumnWidth = 2
        .RowHeight = 14.25
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white
    End With

    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
        Select Case Rng1.Cells(i, j).Value
            Case 3
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 3, 74)
            Case -4142
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Case 1
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1, 1)
            Case 14
                Rng1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 153)
        End Select
        For k = 1 To 100000: Next k 'adds a delay to animate
      Next j
    Next i

    Rng1.Cells(1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: DK:  an eloquent improvement and a nice tightening of the code.  I especially like the case statement. Thank you. Can you help with one more thing?  What I want to do is eliminate the text file and have all the graphical data stored in an array… either a string array or a numerical variant array...  that way a person only has to pick on her cell and initiate the macro and ta-da: Zoidberg !  X=Array(1,0,3,1,0....)  then you perform all of the above code on "X" just like you would parse the text file.

Comment: How will you be distributing the code? Will you send a workbook? An add-in? An exported module?

Comment: when I first run the macro it starts at A1 and scans per cell drawing Zberg.  It resizes the cells and goes blank... all white.  If you change the formatting to the cells to General, then you can see the numbers that will represent the colors.  If you then run it again it hides the first set of numbers and redraws one "array" to the right.  Again, if you change the cells to general you see 1 colored Zberg without numbers and one starting at A1 with numbers...  run it again and another Zberg to the right... At all times the first numeric (uncolored) Zberg is in the array starting at A1

Comment: OK - now I understand your English better... is there any way to take the text after you cut / paste / text to columns... take that array and define it as an "Array" ?  the array will be in the VBA Code, but completely unseen by the user.  the code could write the array to the cells, color the cells, erase the data and then ZOIDBERG

Comment: Sub Test()

    Dim Inx As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:BN48")
    Dim ZoidDots() As Variant
    
    ZoidDots = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    
    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
            With Selection
                .Value = ZoidDots(j - 1)
            End With
            
        'For k = 1 To 1000000: Next k 'adds a delay to animate
      Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I would manually enter all the ZoidDots... my text file... once this populates the cells, then run the other code we made up.

```
Sub ZoidArray()

    Dim Inx As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:BN48")
    Dim ZoidDots() As Variant
    
    ZoidDots = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    
    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
            With Selection
                .Value = ZoidDots(j - 1)
            End With
            
        'For k = 1 To 1000000: Next k 'adds a delay to animate
      Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```